# Somar valores a um atributo de objeto JSON desserializado no Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Meu problema é o seguinte: estou recuperando um objeto Json do localStorage via Javascript, e queria somar um valor a um desses atributos, e depois salvar o objeto d evolta na local storage. Porém, ao fazer a operação: objeto.atributo = objeto.atributo + umValorNumerico; o que acontece é que os valores são concatenados no atributo. Ou seja, ao invés de  1+1 resultarem em dois, o resultado é salvo no Json como "11".

Neste exemplo abaixo, o saldo atual do cliente era 122,00  e eu tentei somar 8772,99.

Os dois zeros que tem na frente é porque não consegui formatar o pattern direito ainda.

Segue o meu código:

```
function processaConfirmDep(){


        var valor = document.getElementById('valorDeposito');
        var favorecido = document.getElementById('nomeFav');



            var objDep;


            var cliente = localStorage.getItem(favorecido.value);
            var clienteConta = JSON.parse(cliente);
            var agenciaFav = clienteConta.agencia;
            var contaFav = clienteConta.conta;

            objDep = {
            id : "12",
            agenciaFav : agenciaFav.value,
            contaFav : contaFav.value,
            valor : valor.value
            }
            clienteConta.saldo = clienteConta.saldo+valor.value;

            var clienteDeposito = createMyObject("DepositoLucas", [clienteConta, objDep]);

            localStorage["DepositoLucas"] = JSON.stringify(clienteDeposito);
            localStorage[clienteConta.nome] = JSON.stringify(clienteConta);

        }
```

Resultado no local Storage. (Veja o objeto de chave "Lucas", atributo "saldo"):

```
{"DepositoLucas":[{"nome":"Lucas","agencia":"33333","conta":"4123","saldo":"0122,008772,99"},{"id":"12","valor":"8772,99"}]}



Lucas {"nome":"Lucas","agencia":"33333","conta":"4123","saldo":"0122,008772,99"}
```

Comment: Antes de fazer a operação. Você deve converter os dados para o tipo **number**. Pode usar a função `parseFloat()`. Pois dessa forma o que está acontecendo é uma operação sobre strings. Por isso é feita uma concatenação.

Comment: Ah, quando for converter os dados. Lembre-se de substituir a vírgula (,) por um ponto (.). Ou seja: 122,00 ficaria 122.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que o valor no objeto jason, está como string, logo ao tentar executar a soma, na verdade está concatenando. Para que seja possível fazer o calculo matemático, deve haver uma conversão utilizando `parseFloat()`, segue baixo seu código *Js*, corrigido:

```
function processaConfirmDep(){

        var valor = document.getElementById('valorDeposito');
        var favorecido = document.getElementById('nomeFav');

        var objDep;

        var cliente = localStorage.getItem(favorecido.value);
        var clienteConta = JSON.parse(cliente);
        var agenciaFav = clienteConta.agencia;
        var contaFav = clienteConta.conta;

        objDep = {
        id : "12",
        agenciaFav : agenciaFav.value,
        contaFav : contaFav.value,
        valor : valor.value
        }

        var valorDepConvertido = parseFloat(valor.value);
        clienteConta.saldo = parseFloat(clienteConta.saldo)+valorDepConvertido;

        var clienteDeposito = createMyObject("DepositoLucas", [clienteConta, objDep]);

        localStorage["DepositoLucas"] = JSON.stringify(clienteDeposito);
        localStorage[clienteConta.nome] = JSON.stringify(clienteConta);

    }
```